# Matlab 2015a install on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 15.10, matlab

After installing Matlab 2015a on Ubuntu 15.10, when I type

```
mex -setup
```

I get

```
Caught "std::exception" Exception message is:
boost::filesystem::status: Permission denied: "/home/shreez/.gvfs"
```

How do I resolve this issue ?

Comment: and what permissions are set for the `/home/shreez/.gvfs`? If this is a directory run `ls -ld /home/shreez/.gvfs` to check them.

Comment: Indeed, I do not have Permission to that location.  However, I cannot issue `fusermount -u ~/.gvfs` or add write permission using  `chmod`. This is what I get when I issue command fusermount    `fusermount: entry for /home/shreez/.gvfs not found in /etc/mtab`

Comment: Hmm, I found [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/405201/accidentally-moved-fuse-mounted-mount-point-not-cannot-unmount-any-option-besi) question which describes the same problem with unmounting. It seems like some process is responsible for this.

Comment: `sudo umount ~/.gvfs` seems to do the trick, but I am not sure what side-effects it has, as my understanding is rather limited.

Answer (score 1):

It could be related to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/212789). If you are not able to change the permissions of that folder (using `chmod`) you can unmount `~/.gvfs` manually:

```
$ fusermount -u ~/.gvfs
```

since as long it is mounted you can not change its permissions.

Comment: @markkirby could and somehow because we don't know the whole picture based on the short question. Clear is only that the permissions of that folder cause his problem. So thats why unmounting can help to resolve it.

Comment: @markkirby look, his problem = `Permission denied: "/home/shreez/.gvfs"` my answer for sure will fix it right? Since as long its mounted he can not change the permissions right? I understand your point but based on the question this is (at least in my opinion) a valid answer If you don't like it just vote it down.

Comment: I never said it was not right, I am saying the language you use indicates you don't know that you are right, now in comments you say it will fix it for sure, then why did you not sat that in the answer? I don't want to downvote you, I want to upvote you, but I cannot do that on an answer that is worded like a guess, just remove `try` and `somehow` to make your answer an actual answer, do you see my point?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo umount ~/.gvfs
```

seems to do the trick, but I am not sure what side-effects it has, as my understanding is rather limited.